# MPEG2(MPEG 2) TS Hardware Interface

Tags: hardware, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

Hi I have an mpeg connection that I am trying to read. It has 4 signals. clock, data, valid and sync. Now for some reason I don't see the sync byte when the sync signal is active. I am thinking since there is a sync signal they have eliminated the need for a sync byte. Is there such provision in the MPEG2 protocol. Also since the ISO standard for MPEG2 is paid it would be great if someone can point to some free resources that explain the protocol.

Comment: Is the data signal a 8 bit bus or only a single bit (=serial)? The sync byte should be present on the data signal while the sync bit is high. Also you should be able to find the right ISO standard by googling for it, ISO 13818-1.

Comment: Data signal is 8 bit bus. Don't we need to pay for the iso?